# Guest Session rename

Tags: rename, guest-session

I need a way to rename `Guest Session` in login screen and make it `Students`, or create a guest account whit the same behavior, somebody can help me?

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonably simple way to do that. Please see my comments on the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the guest account from the login screen. It doesn't sound like you 
need it anyway. You can always undo your changes

Always make backups of your files

```
sudo cp /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.original
sudo vi /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following lines

```
[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest=false
```

Restart service

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Try to login guest session, it is gone!
Add your user.

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /tmp/students -c "Students Session"  students
```

Let them login without password:

```
$ sudo passwd -d students
passwd: password expiry information changed
```

Their home directory won't survive a reboot, so we create their home directory using `/etc/rc.local` on each reboot:

```
sudo cp /etc/rc.local /etc/rc.local.original
sudo vi /etc/rc.local
```

Add:

```sh
if [ ! -d /tmp/students ] ; then
    mkdir -p /tmp/students ;
    chmod 0711 /tmp/students ;
    cp -a  /etc/skel/.[!.]* /tmp/students/ ;
    chown -R students:students /tmp/students
fi
```

Comment: That's a creative idea, even if a reboot is required to reset the account. One detail: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` doesn't exist by default nowadays. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html#disable) is the recommended way to disable guest session.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to reset the account of logout... :)

Comment: Also, even though /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf doesn't exist, you can still create it.  Same result!

Comment: It works, but at least I think you should drop the greeter-session part, which is completely unrelated.